# using slice in an array doesn't affect the template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have an array `availableBoats` and I am rendering its elements using the following code snippet:

```
<app-boat *ngFor="let b of availableBoats" [size]="b.size" [(available)]="b.available" [type]="b.type" ></app-boat>
```

I was expecting that when I remove one boat from the array using the `.slice()` function, it won't appear anymore in the template. Am I doing something wrong or this is not the expected behavior in Angular?

At some point, the following code is called. I tested it setting a break-point there and I can see that the boat was removed:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.availableBoats.length; i++) {
  const b = this.availableBoats[i];
  if (b.type === this.selectedBoatType) {   
    this.availableBoats.slice(i, 1);
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: We don't know, because you didn't post your code. But slice doesn't remove an element from an array. Read its documentation carefully: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: ^^^ what he said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was expecting that when I remove one boat from the array using the
>   .slice() function, it won't appear anymore in the template.

Your assumptions are incorrect because [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> (...) returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array
>   object selected from begin to end (end not included). **The original
>   array will not be modified**.

In order to mutate the array you need to use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) which

> (...) **changes the contents of an array** by removing existing elements
>   and/or adding new elements

Hence `this.availableBoats.slice(i, 1);` is not removing any element from `this.availableBoats`.

In order to do that use `this.availableBoats.splice(i, 1);`